# Is Intuitionistic Quantified Propositional Logic decidable like the classical case?

Tags: logic

Is the Intuitionistic version of Quantified Propositional Logic (http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/quantification/#QuaProLog) decidable like the classical case? If not, are there other logic variants where the Quantified Propositional case is undecidable (e.g. three valued logics, partial logic, ...)?

Comment: It seems not; see : Dov M. Gabbay, [Semantical Investigations in Heyting’s Intuitionistic Logic-Springer Netherlands](https://books.google.it/books?id=3ZHtCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA262) (1981), page 262 : **Ch.14.6** UNDECIDABILITY OF SECOND ORDER PROPOSITIONAL CALCULUS.

Comment: I also found these: S. Kripke, [The Undecidability of Monadic Modal Quantification Theory](http://phdtree.org//pdf/46190781-the-undecidability-of-monadic-modal-quantification-theory/) and [Quantified Boolean Conundrum](https://queuea9.wordpress.com/2011/03/24/quantified-boolean-conundrum/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is equivalent to the problem of inhabitation in System F which is well known to be undecidable, see the paper by Pawel Urzyzyn.
https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-62688-3_47